# How to take backup and restore Elastic Search data from n node cluster to m node cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I have my ES cluster running on 3 nodes but in some instances, it can be scaled to 5 or 7 as well. I need to upgrade my 5/7 nodes ES cluster.

Will taking a snapshot  from n nodes cluster and restoring to m nodes cluster work ?

Comment: Do you want to take a snapshot from a cluster and restore it in another cluster or you just want to increase the number of nodes the same cluster?

Comment: i have a scaled cluster with 5 nodes. Now i want to take back up from this cluster and restore into another 3 node cluster.

Comment: You can create a snapshot on one cluster and restore it in another cluster without any problem, elasticsearch will distribute the shards and replicas according the settings of each index in your snapshot and the nodes available. Both cluster need to have access to the snapshot repository.

Comment: Thanks @leandrojmp